# I have a problem in next-auth SignIn Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I use **Nextjs 13.2.4** in my project and I use for authentication **next-auth 4.22.0**:

I have a problem when I submit the login form ,The problem is in the **SignIn** function, I get this error .

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

this is in the **"/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js"**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { compare } from "bcryptjs";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
export const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      id: "login_id",
      name: "Sign In",

      async authorize(credentials) {
        const user = {
          id: "1",
          password: "hicham",
          email: "test@gmail.com",
          name: "hicham zak",
        };
        // if (user) return user;
        // else return null;
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }


        // test
        if (!user || credentials.password !== user.password) {
          return null;
        }

        return {
          id: user.id,
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
          randomKey: "Hey cool",
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      console.log("JWT Callback", { token, user });
      if (user) {
        const u = user;
        return {
          ...token,
          id: u.id,
          randomKey: u.randomKey,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

and this is login Component **LoginForm.jsx**

```
"use client";
import Label from "../ui/Label";
import Input from "../ui/Input";
import Link from "next/link";
import Btn from "../ui/Btn";
import { useState } from "react";
import ShowHidePass from "../ShowHidePass";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { loginValidate } from "../../lib/validate";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Alert from "../ui/Alert";

export const contentType = "application/json";

const Form = ({ btn }) => {
  // this for formik
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validate: loginValidate,
    onSubmit,
  });
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const callbackUrl = searchParams.get("callbackUrl") || "/home";

  // states
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  // this for hide and show the password
  const [showPass, setShowPass] = useState(false);
  function handelShowPass(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowPass(!showPass);
  }
  // this function excute in submission
  //  I HAVE A PROBLEM IN THIS FUNCTION I SHOULD FIX IT LATER
  async function onSubmit(values) {
    try {
      const result = await signIn("login_id", {
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        password: "test123455",
        redirect: false,
        callbackUrl,
      });
      console.log(result);
      if (!result?.error) router.push(callbackUrl);
      else setError("Invalid email or password");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  return (
    <form
      method="post"
      className="space-y-8 sm1:w-[400px]"
      onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
    >
      <div className="grid w-full items-center gap-1.5">
        <Label htmlFor={"email"} text={"Email"} />

        <Input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter your email"
          formik={formik.getFieldProps("email")}
          style={`
            ${
              formik.errors.email && formik.touched.email
                ? "border-red-600 "
                : ""
            }
            hover:border-b-primary hover:border-b-2 hover:rounded-none hover:rounded-b-md
          `}
        />
      </div>

      <div className={"grid w-full items-center gap-1.5"}>
        <Label htmlFor="pass" text={"Password"} />
        <Input
          name="password"
          type={showPass ? "text" : "password"}
          placeholder="Enter your Password"
          children={
            <ShowHidePass showPass={showPass} handelShowPass={handelShowPass} />
          }
          formik={formik.getFieldProps("password")}
          style={`
            ${
              formik.errors.password && formik.touched.password
                ? "border-red-600 "
                : ""
            }
            hover:border-b-primary hover:border-b-2 hover:rounded-none hover:rounded-b-md
            `}
        />
      </div>
      {error && <Alert children={error} />}
      <div className="w-full text-center pb-2 font-semibold text-sm">
        <Link href="/forgot-password" className="text-indigo-500">
          Forgot password?
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="w-full">
        <Btn btnText={btn} type={"submit"} />
      </div>

      <div className="w-full text-center pb-2 font-semibold text-sm">
        <span>Create an account? </span>
        <Link href="/signUp" className="text-indigo-500 hover:underline">
          Sign Up
        </Link>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

and then I call that component In the login page:

```
import Form from "../../../../components/form/LoginForm";
import Logo from "../../../../components/Logo";

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen w-screen sm1:flex sm1:justify-center sm1:items-center ">
      <div className="sm1:shadow-xl bg-slate-200 sm1:bg-white sm1:rounded-lg px-8 pt-12 pb-8 space-y-12">
        <Logo />
        <h1 className="text-2xl my-8 font-semibold">Login to your account</h1>
        <Form btn={"Login"} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```